# How to query date time between start time and end time in another pyspark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 tables
one having a start time and end time filed

```
+---------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|channelId|starttime               |endtime                |
+---------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|1        |2022-03-31 18:57:46.329|2022-03-31 18:58:46.329|
|2        |2022-03-31 18:58:48.61 |2022-03-31 18:59:48.61 |
+---------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

2nd table has the time series data

```
|channelId|time                   |
+---------+-----------------------+
|1        |2022-03-31 18:58:46.329|
|1        |2022-03-31 18:58:46.329|
|1        |2022-03-31 18:58:46.329|
|2        |2022-03-31 18:59:48.61 |
+---------+-----------------------+
```

I want to query data from the 2nd table between of 1st table time range for both channelId

expected 2 data frames

```
|channelId|time                   |
+---------+-----------------------+
|1        |2022-03-31 18:58:46.329|
|1        |2022-03-31 18:58:46.329|
|1        |2022-03-31 18:58:46.329|
```

and

```
|2        |2022-03-31 18:59:48.61 |
+---------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Can you explain the use case here ? It's slightly confusing!

Comment: And what do you want to do with those partitions? More calculation or save them separately?